# If $X$ has $S^{2n}$ as universal covering space then $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I proved that if $f:S^{n}\rightarrow S^n$ has no fixed points then $\mathrm{deg}(f)=(-1)^{n+1}$. I want to use this to show that If $X$ has $S^{2n}$ as universal covering space then $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

**My attempt**:

Since $S^{2n} \rightarrow X$ is the universal covering space, it follows that the group of deck transformations $G$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X)$. If $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial we are done so suppose $\pi_1(X)$ is not.

Take two nontrivial element $id \neq f,g \in G$. Since $S^{2n}$ is path-connected, the deck transformation is determined by a single fiber so $f$ and $g$ cannot have any fixed points. Therefore, $\mathrm{deg}(f) = (-1)^{2n+1} = -1 = \mathrm{deg}(g)$. Thus, $$\mathrm{deg}(f \circ f) = \mathrm{deg}(f)^2 = 1$$ and $$\mathrm{deg} (g \circ f) = \mathrm{deg}(g) \mathrm{deg}(f) = 1$$ How do I rigorously assert that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ from here?

I am confused because $\mathrm{deg}(g \circ f) = 1$ doesn't mean that $g \circ f = id$ right? If not, are the group of deck transformations defined up to homotopy and $g \circ f \simeq id$?

Comment: $g\circ g= id, g\circ f= id\implies g\circ g\circ f=g\implies f=g.$

Comment: Just a comment that the odd case is a [much harder problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8187) but the collection of such groups can still be classified!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused because $\mathrm{deg}(g \circ f) = 1$ doesn't mean that $g \circ f = id$ right?

Not in general. This fails to be true for odd dimensional spheres or when dealing with non-Deck maps. But ultimately it is true in this case.

> If not, are the group of deck transformations defined up to homotopy and $g \circ f \simeq id$?

No, Deck transformations **are not** defined up to homotopy. These are concrete, special homeomorphisms together with function composition. You are right that $g\circ f\simeq id$ but this is not enough for us. In general, Deck transformations can be homotopic but not equal (and in such case they will correspond to different elements of $\pi_1(X)$). But of course not in our case.

---

You are very close. You just need a purely algebraic argument. In current situation $\mathrm{deg}:G\to\{-1,1\}$ is a group homomorphism. And so the condition "$\mathrm{deg}(f)=-1$ when $f\neq id$" means that the kernel of $\mathrm{deg}$ is trivial. And therefore $\mathrm{deg}$ is injective, which finally means that (up to isomorphism) $G$ has to be a subgroup of $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you!!! What a clean argument!

Comment: Is it true that if $f: X \rightarrow X$ and $\mathrm{deg}(f) = 1$ then $f \simeq id_X$? Or is this true for the special case when $X=S^{n}$ but not in general?

Comment: What's also fascinating about your answer is that I didn't have to even use the argument that $\mathrm{deg}(f \circ g) = 1 = \mathrm{deg}(f \circ f)$ (in fact, not enough as you mentioned)

Comment: @mathlover314 no, $deg(f)=1$ implies that $f\simeq id$ only for spheres. I'm glad you enjoyed my answer. :)